# Output of 'ldd' to dictionary

Tags: python, parsing, hash-map, child-process

I want to use the output of the terminal command `ldd`:

```
root@kali-vm:~/Desktop# ldd simple
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7722000)
    libcurl-gnutls.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4 (0xb769c000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb7539000)
    libidn.so.11 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11 (0xb7505000)
```

And use it to build a dictionary that uses the library name as key and the path to the library as value. I've come up with this little Python snippet:

```
  # Get List of Librairies in Dictionary
  lddOut = subprocess.check_output(['ldd', fileName])
  libraries = {}
  for line in lddOut.splitlines():
    arr = line.split(" => ")
    library = arr[0].strip('\t')
    try:
      path = arr[1].split(' (0x')[0]
    except:
      pass
    libraries[library] = path
```

It works fine for my needs but I'm at the point where I don't want my code to just work but want it optimized and well structured/programmed. How can I improve this snippet?

EDIT: Note that I do not want the address (ie 0xbxxxxxx) in my dictionary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This kind of parsing by pattern matching is much better done using a regular expression.

```
import re

libraries = {}
for line in ldd_out.splitlines():
    match = re.match(r'\t(.*) => (.*) \(0x', line)
    if match:
        libraries[match.group(1)] = match.group(2)
```